# Because PIL expects a file object, I'm trying to use tempfile to create a file. Running into what I think are buffer problems

Tags: python, file, file-io, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a temporary file from an entry in my database. I have done a `print(filedata['data'])` and I can see that the data is being retrieved properly but even with the `temp_h.flush()` I never see any data saved to the file. When I go to retrieve it, the file is empty. Could someone please explain to me what's causing this and if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do with PIL, I'd love to learn that too. I'm running this on a Linux system with an EXT3 File system

```
def main():
    '''Main'''

    for nohisto in thestash.stash.get_files():
       fileid = str(nohisto['_id'])
       filedata = openstash(fileid)
       temp_h = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='r+')
       temp_h.write(filedata['data'])
       temp_h.flush()
       time.sleep(3)
       myhisto = Image.open(temp_h).histogram()
```

Comment: Another option for you is to use the stringIO Python modulke so that you won't need to write your data to a file before passing it to PIL to create an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `mode='w+'`, then after writing, `seek(0)` to put the i/o pointer back to the file beginnning.  You can also create in-memory file-like objects using the StringIO module.

Comment: Thanks, adding the seek worked. I usually create one handle for reading and one for writing.

Comment: `seek()` is such an infrequently used method that it's easy to not realize when you need it...